# Custom UIBarButtonItem with quartz

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, quartz-2d, uicontrol

How can I draw a button with quartz that has exactly the same style as a UIBarButtonItem. The button should be able to show different colors. 
I downloaded the Three20 project, but this project is really complex, you'd need a lot of time to overlook the whole framework. I just want to draw a custom UIBarButtonItem.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Three20 library, I guess TTButton's "toolbarButton" style is what you want. TTButton is a sub-class of UIButton, but it allows you to apply styles just like using css while creating a webpage.

To create a button like a UIBarButtonItem, just call

```
[TTButton buttonWithStyle:@"toolbarButton:" title:@"Title"]
```

You may need to retain it since the button is an auto-release object.

Answer (score 1):

Try a UISegmentedControl with only one segment and momentary selection. It supports tintColor and might be close enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4.1**

You can add  your own custom view with your own designs/animations/colors/etc using Quartz2D as follows.

- Create your custom view with your custom Quartz stuff
- Add your UIBarButtonItem with a customView
- Add a protocol (you will need it, because the UIBarButtonItem initialized wit a customView expects the view to handle user interactions and thus does not provide a way to set a target/selector)

> The bar button item created by this method does not call the action
>   method of its target in response to user interactions. Instead, the
>   bar button item expects the specified custom view to handle any user
>   interactions and provide an appropriate response.

Don't forget to add that your view has to conform to the protocol (`CameraButtonDelegate` in this case) and also to add the method `cameraButtonChanged(to:)` to capture the user interactions

```
func setupButton() {
   customView = CameraButton()
   customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
   customView.delegate = self
   let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView:customView)
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = torchItem
}

protocol CameraButtonDelegate {
    func cameraButtonChanged(to state:Bool)
}
class CameraButton: UIView {
    var delegate: CameraButtonDelegate?
    var active: Bool = false    
    var strokeColor = UIColor.gray
    init() {
        self.init()
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.active = self.active ? false : true
        self.strokeColor = self.active ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.gray
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.delegate?.cameraButtonChanged(to: self.active)
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setStrokeColor(strokeColor.cgColor)
        context?.setLineWidth(1.0)
        // Add your Quartz stuff here
        context?.strokePath()
    }
}
```