# How to create custom UIBarButtonItem without glossy effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, uibarbuttonitem

I use Three20 to create UIBarButtonItem as shown in this StackOverFlow question:

[Custom UIBarButtonItem with quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257690/custom-uibarbuttonitem-with-quartz)

now I what that UIBarButtonItem have no glossy effect and can have different color (light color and dark color).

Do you know how to do it?

**UPDATE**:

and I would like to do it without using images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use initWithCustomView on UIBarButtonItem and using it you can basically put in that view what ever you want - TTButton, UIButton, custom UIView, etc...